# Ubuntu 17.10 cannot open Root folder

Tags: updates

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and after updating, now i cant open the Root folder. each time i go to `other locations` then `Computer` and try opening it, it just closes the files folder.
what could be the problem.

Comment: What is the result of `ls -ld /` typed in a terminal (opened with Ctrl-Alt-T)? Please insert the answer into your question.

Comment: this is the result of `ls -ld /`
`drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan 27 06:47 /`

Comment: actually each time my machine hibernates, it kills all processes. It's like I'm rebooting again.

Answer (score 0):

Root's home directory is /root, not /

You have no permission to read root's home directory without sudo (or similar).

```
grep root /etc/passwd
```

> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

will show root's home directory

`ls -ld /root`

> drwx------ 14 root root 4096 Nov  3 20:50 /root

will show that directory's permissions.

Sounds like everything is working as it should.

If you need to see the contents of root's home directory, do this:

> Open a terminal window

```
$sudo bash
```

> (enter password. You are now root. BE CAREFUL!)

```
# ls -l /root (Note your prompt when root is a #)
```

> (other commands as needed. You are now root. BE CAREFUL!)

```
#exit (to exit root)
```

Comment: mine shows this 
`drwx------ 13 root root 4096 Jan 25 15:31 /root`

when i run `sudo ls -ld /root`

why is there a 13 instead of 14?
could i be the problem?

Comment: @TimothyMach That number (13 or 14) is the number of links to the file. But what IS your problem other than you can't access the file unless you are root? THAT is not a problem. I have updated my answer to show you how to see the contents of root's home directory if you need to look at it.